# JApplet code runs when embed

Tags: java, security, file-io, applet, japplet

Does Java Applet runs all the codes in the class when it is embedded in a JSP? This might sound silly but when I run a standalone applet, I can manage to write an image to a path. But when I embed the applet to a JSP page, it appears but it seems like the writing image code doesn't seem to be executed as I do not see any image being created on the directory I have specified.

Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Are you getting confused by relative paths of the JSP source file within the server, and the http URL of the generated HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Java Applet runs all the codes in the class when it is embedded in a JSP?

Yes and no.  It tries to run all the codes, but some things are not allowed by the `SecurityManager`.

> Can anyone explain to me?

If you look in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) you might see a helpful and informative `AccessControlException` (presuming the code does not catch and ignore errors).  By default an applet cannot access the local file system.

Comment: I see, I guess that's the problem with Java 1.6 onwards. Sad.

Comment: No, it has been the case since applets were introduced in (at least as far back as) Java 1.1.  And no, not sad.  If applets could write files without any checking or authentication, the hackers long ago would have abused that to infect machines surfing around the net.  If that was the case, Java would have a very bad name and **nobody** would have Java installed.